# hadoop mapreduce with python error in implement of two table join

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop. I use python to implement a join of two table.

A table with student info as stu id and name and another table with grade info as stu id, class id and grade.(The data is in the end of this question)

with cat ./data* | python mapper.py |sort|  python reducer.py

I get the right answer, however in the hadoop process, I get the following error:

INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1456069308240_0019_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
the code is below:

mapper code:

```
import os

import sys

def mapper():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if len(line.strip())== 0:
            continue        
        field = line[:-1].split('\t')
        if len(field) ==2:
            print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (field[0],'0',field[1])
        elif len(field) ==3:
            print '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (field[0],'1',field[1],field[2])

if __name__=='__main__':   
    mapper()
```

reducer code:

```
def reducer():
    lastsno=""
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if len(line.strip())== 0:
            continue
        field = line[:-1].split('\t')
        sno = field[0]
        if sno != lastsno:
            name = ""
            if field[1] == "0":
                name = field[2]
        elif sno == lastsno:
            if field[1] == "1":
                courseno =field[2]
                grade = field[3]
                if name:
                    print '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (lastsno,name,courseno,grade)
        lastsno = sno

if __name__=='__main__':   
    reducer()
```

the data is just below

datainfo:

```
2014211011  taiyuan
2014211012  tiantian
2014211013  kk
2014211014  tank
2014211015  lc
2014211016  wjs
2014211017  gyc
2014211018  hd
2014211019  cx
```

data_grade:

```
2014211012  011 80
2014211012  012 95
2014211013  011 40
2014211014  013 38
2014211011  011 35
2014211013  022 40
2014211015  011 80
```

with above cat python script, I can get right answer below:

```
2014211011  taiyuan 011 35
2014211012  tiantian    011 80
2014211012  tiantian    012 95
2014211013  kk  011 40
2014211013  kk  022 40
2014211014  tank    013 38
2014211015  lc  011 80
```

But error in hadoop, please help me, Thanks.

Comment: the hadoop command i use was below :  hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar  -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input join_exp/* -output joinexpoutput/ -file mapper.py -file reducer.py

Comment: or hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar -D mapred.map.tasks=10 -D mapred.reduce.tasks=5 -D mapred.job.map.capacity=10 -D mapred.job.reduce.capacity=5 -D num.key.fields.for.partition=1 -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 -partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input join_exp/* -output joinexpoutput/ -file mapper.py -file reducer.py

Comment: I got the answer, the python path problem,add #!/usr/bin/env python in the head, the problem is ok